# Lucene.net filters: do they restrict the initial search space or just exclude filtered docs from search results?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to determine whether Lucene.net filters restrict the search space or just exclude documents from search matches based on the documents returned by the filter.  That is, if a filter allows for documents A,B, and C but not D and E and a user's query matches B,C, and D, would the filter prevent D from even being considered as a query match, or would the query matches include B,C, and D and then just have D excluded by the filter after the query runs?  I'm not finding conclusive information anywhere on this front.  The closest I've come is this post from a year and a half ago: http://java.dzone.com/news/fast-lucene-search-filters which suggests that filters are applied after the query matches are returned.  Keep in mind that I'm using the current version of Lucene.net, NOT Lucene for Java.

Comment: Lucene.net is almost an exact port of lucene java, this kind of stuff will behave exactly the same in both versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **current** Lucene.Net, Filters are applied after query execution. Therefore, documents excluded by the filter would still be scored per the query criterias and then removed from the result set.

That is changing in 4.x, see [Lucene-1536](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1536) for more informations.

Now you might ask, is it worth is to use filters? The answer is yes, if you cache the Filter for re-use.

Comment: What if I already have the doc ids I want the query to be valid for available to me?  In that case is there any difference between just writing my own collector that would discard anything not matching one of those ids vs using a filter?

Comment: In that case, personally, I'd go with the custom collector approach.